# javascript - pass reference of class property to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to send class property as parameter to addEventListener. Doing this is because when the event occurs, I'm no longer in the context of the class (this) and can't get\set the value of the property. I need somehow pass a reference of the property to the function.
I'm aware that I can add the property as attribute to the event target and reach it like this, but I quite sure that there should be a more straight forward solution.
This is the relevant code:

```
export class ZZZZZ{
 constructor() 
{
  this.activeTooltip = null; //This is the relevant property
}

YYYYFunc()
{
  /*thinking of doing it like that*/
  var activeTooltip = this.activeTooltip;
  cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', function() { XXXFunc(activeTooltip)});
}

XXXFunc(activeTooltip)
{
   var A = this.activeTooltip; //I'm not in the context of the class - 
                               //"this" is irrelevant - it is null
   var B = activeTooltip;
}
```

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess it's full dupe. They appear every single day.

Comment: @estus: I know; I close them. :-) To me it isn't quite because he/she isn't asking how to make `this` mean something particular in `XXXFunc`, but rather whether what he/she is doing above is okay or clunky. But I can see it both ways.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing it works and is fairly common, but note that there's no reason you can't make `this` in `XXXFunc` your instance, by using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', XXXFunc.bind(this));
```

`bind` returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to the value you give `bind`. So that will call `XXXFunc` with `this` referring to your instance, and `this.activeTooltip` will work within it.

There are other ways as well. In ES5 and earlier, you can use [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with a variable you close over:

```
var _this = this;
cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', function() { XXXFunc.call(_this)});
```

In ES2015+, you can use an arrow function instead of the variable, since the arrow function closes over `this` itself:

```
cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', () => XXXFunc.call(this));
```

In both cases, again, `this` in `XXXFunc` refers to your instance, so `this.activeTooltip` works.

And of course, if `XXXFunc` where a method on the instance, it would be even cleaner:

ES5- using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', this.XXXFunc.bind(this));
```

ES2015+ using an arrow function:

```
cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', () => this.XXXFunc());
```